# How to check a website in BlackBerry Simulator

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, blackberry-10

How can I debug a Responsive site in Blackberry Q10 device, I don't have the device, but someone reported an issue with the menu in BlackBerry Q10, now I Can't debug it until I see the issue and inspect the HTML/CSS to see what is the problem.

I want to be able to view a website exact way how it will look in BlackBerry, I am on windows 7, and I have tried Chorme Emulator, Also download two simulators for BB, but it didn't work.

Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to download and install a BB10 Simulator that should run in your Win 7 environment and then you can test directly.  That, in my opinion, is the best way to test.

You will need to install a VMware solution and run it as a virtual machine.  But I think the documentation explains this process quite well - you will find it all here:

[simulator](http://developer.blackberry.com/devzone/develop/simulator/index.html)

If you do have problems with this, then please give us something more than "it didn't work".  If you look at the documentation, you will see that it should work, and it works on my Win 7 system, so I suspect there is a problem with your system or installation rather than the Simulator itself.  But "it didn't work" does not give any idea where to start to help you with this.

Comment: Hey @Peter Strange sorry about not giving you details about the simulators, I was actually focusing on the site, thinking of Simulators as a secondary thing. Thanks for helping, I am actually going to install the VMware, and install this simulator now. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

You wont be able to inspect the HTML/CSS on the device as it is highly unlikely for you to be able to view the source. Your best option is to find out what mobile browser it is running and then try emulating it in the same resolution.

It looks like the blackberry 10.2OS default browser uses `web kit` so a browser that runs on the same engine should display the same things.

The Q10 resolution is 720x720 so try to emulate a `web kit` browser in that resolution and you'll be as close as possible without having the actual device.

If your still showing no problem, then i guess you'll have to find yourself a q10 to test it out on or ask the user with the problems with a full detail description of the problem and a picture to go with it